# Why my input Validator is always showing message in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, validation, angular8, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have the follwing form:

```
<form [formGroup]="claimForm">
<header class="card-header bg-red">
  <h2>Repairer Information</h2>
</header>
<div class="card-body p-3">
  <div class="tab-content pb-4" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="row my-4">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="repairerName">Repairer Contact Name</label>
        <input matInput class="form-control" formControlName="repairerName"
              [(ngModel)]="repairerName">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="repairerEmail">Repairer Email Address</label>
        <input matInput class="form-control"
          placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com"
          formControlName="emailValidator"
          [formControl]="f.emailFormControl"
          [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
          [(ngModel)]="repairerEmail">
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.emailValidator.hasError('email') && !f.emailValidator.hasError('required')">
          Please enter a valid email address
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.emailValidator.hasError('required')">
          Email is <strong>required</strong>
        </mat-error>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-icon btn-secondary" [routerLink]="['/claims/create/2']">
      <i class="material-icons">check_circle_outline</i><span>Continue</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my .ts file:

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  templateUrl: './repairer-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./repairer-info.component.scss'],
  animations: [BottomToUpAnimation()]
})
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {

 repairerEmail = '';

 submitted = false;

 // Form information
 claimForm: FormGroup;

 matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.claimForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      emailValidator: [ this.repairerEmail, [Validators.required, Validators.email] ]
  });
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.claimForm.controls; }

}
```

I used code from this [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eqojbjjyeke?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html).

As it should work, it will say email is mandatory when you do some interaction using the input or submitting. But my error message is always being shown:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Why is the error message for the `required` property being shown always even if I don't do anything with my input?

*EDIT:* I tried to remove placeholder or set it to a valid value the error is still there. Same happens when trying to remove the ngModel.

Comment: As per the image attached, the text which shows there is a placeholder comes from ```placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com"``` and it is not real value, so it throws error as required.. If you start typing then this required error would gone..

Comment: Even if I remove the placeholder or set it with a valid email, it's still not working.

Comment: If you remove placeholder then it will be empty value so you will get the error message.. Only if you type on input it will go and that is the requirement right?? What is your need?? Do you want to append default input value to input??

Comment: I want to not validate until it remains untouched and nothing has been written on it. Just exactly as the example.

Comment: Then follow the example provided.. You are not supposed to give both ```[(ngModel)]``` and ```[formControl]``` to a single input element..

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz with your code? Which would be easier for debugging..

Comment: I cannot make the stackblitz work... I never used it

Comment: Do you need like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsj3s9

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. It doesn't send any validation info until you interact with the input field.

Comment: Yes that is what happened in the provided link right??

Comment: Yes, but not in my code :(

Comment: Then you need to compare both the code..The example also contains your code only so compare it..

Comment: Check this line mainly, ```<mat-error *ngIf="f.emailValidator.touched ...```, it only does that requirement..